# In Neo4j Graphql Apollo server type definition how to add names with spaces?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql, grandstack

My type definition is like this

```
type COMPANY {
    "AIRLINE SEGMENT": String             
    AIRLINE_TYPE: String
}
```

I get an error saying

```
apollo server GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found :
```

If I remove the space and quotes then I don't get an error. I have searched everywhere but I haven't a way to add names with spaces in them.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GraphQL does not support spaces within names. According to the [spec](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Names), names must match the following regular expression:

```
/[_A-Za-z][_0-9A-Za-z]*/
```

GraphQL actually ignores **all** white space within a document, with the exception of white space within Strings and Comments:

> White space is used to improve legibility of source text and act as separation between tokens, and any amount of white space may appear before or after any token. White space between tokens is not significant to the semantic meaning of a GraphQL Document, however white space characters may appear within a String or Comment token.

You probably shouldn't be using spaces within node names in the first place, even if they are technically supported. This is the [recommended naming convention](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/naming/#_recommendations):

> Camel case, beginning with an upper-case character

If your data source returns an object with fields whose names include spaces, you can convert these to "legal" field names inside your resolver map. For example, given a type named `Company` with a field called `airlineSegment`:

```
const resolvers = {
  Company: {
    airlineSegment: company => company['AIRLINE SEGMENT']
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and this doesn't work. My neo4j database is not in my control. There are columns with spaces in them and I need to access them. In your resolver the company variable does not have the required field.

Comment: Is there a way to provide my own cypher query in the resolver?

Comment: The resolver was just an example. The value of `company` would depend on whatever the resolving field actually returned. Hard to make any specific recommendations without actually seeing your code. Are you not writing your own queries already? How else are you populating the data in your server? Are you using `neo4j-graphql-js`?

Comment: I was writing my own queries till now in a REST api. I just thought of using neo4j-graphql-js and thats when I faced this problem. I thought for simple stuff like fetching columns I will use neo4jgraphql function but I guess I will write my own cypher queries in the resolver.

Comment: Looks like `neo4j-graphql-js` is a bit limited in that sense. If you want to continue using it, you might be able to use the `@cypher` directive to run a cypher for a specific field. If you only have a handful of fields that have this issue, that may be the way to go.

Comment: So here is what I did for neo4j-graphql-js.
In the resolver function where I fetch all the nodes I replaced ```neo4jgraphql``` function with my own cypher query and fetched the data from the db. Converted that into an array of nodes that contains all the fields and returned that. After that your resolver function works.

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct as I derived my answer from your comments. Thanks a lot